# Sorting with a recursive function

Tags: python, function, sorting, recursion

The task is to sort a 2d array to make it look like a tree. The first number in each list is a personal ID, next is a parent ID, finally goes the name. Sorting is based on connection  between a parent and a child. Child has a parent personal ID as a parent ID.

Example input(order can be mixed):

```
[[0, -1, 'Root'],
[1, 0, 'Left branch'],
[2, 0, 'Right branch'],
[3, 1, 'Left leaf of the Left branch'],
[4, 1, 'Right leaf of the Left branch'],
[5, 2, 'Left leaf of the Right branch'],
[6, 2, 'Right leaf of the Right branch'],
[7, 6, 'Left side of the Right leaf of the Right branch'],
[8, 6, 'Right side of the Right leaf of the Right branch']]
```

Example output:

```
Root
┣╸Left branch
┃ ┣╸Left leaf of the Left branch
┃ ┗╸Right leaf of the Left branch
┗╸Right branch
  ┣╸Left leaf of the Right branch
  ┗╸Right leaf of the Right branch
    ┣╸Left side of the Right leaf of the Right branch
    ┗╸Right side of the Right leaf of the Right branch
```

I've decided to use a recursive function, but can't get which **parameters** are required. The main problem is that on some levels (e.g.'Right side of the Right leaf of the Right branch') we have only 'brothers', so we dont need extra '|' before the line name.
That's my code which doesn't work properly, it adds extra '|':

```
def sort_tree(array, root=-1, grandparents=-1, parent=-1):
    for i in array:
        if i[1] == parent:
            brothers_index = []
            for x in array:
                if x[1] == parent:
                    brothers_index.append(array.index(x))
            if i[1] == root:
                print(i[2])
            elif array.index(i) in brothers_index[0:-1]:
                print('┃ ' * grandparents + '┣╸' + i[2])
            elif array.index(i) == brothers_index[-1]:
                print('┃ ' * grandparents + '┗╸' + i[2])
            sort_tree(array, grandparents = grandparents+1, parent=i[0])
```

Output:

```
Root
┣╸Left branch
┃ ┣╸Left leaf of the Left branch
┃ ┗╸Right leaf of the Left branch
┗╸Right branch
┃ ┣╸Left leaf of the Right branch
┃ ┗╸Right leaf of the Right branch
┃ ┃ ┣╸Left side of the Right leaf of the Right branch
┃ ┃ ┗╸Right side of the Right leaf of the Right branch
```

Could you help me? I know that the task can be solved with dict of dicts, but I really want to make this work.

Comment: Have you thought about creating classes for leaf and branch? To do so would clarify your code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that's going to work. There can be a random amount of joints from a root to a final child (root -- branch -- leaf -- side of the leaf -- part of the side of the leaf -- ...

Comment: O it works. It's a classic example of encoding a tree structure.

Comment: @python_user yes, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Nicholas Hunter so, there shall be 2 classes: for a parent and a child?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure the function is able to determine when it needs to print the space or the `┃` . That means that at the moment of printing, it needs to know if there is another branch coming up or not.
You state at your input that it can be in mixed order. That means that it needs to parse the whole input first before it can begin to print.

So you have 2 choices:

- You fix it at the input by either specifying the structure in a more look-ahead fashion or you make sure it's ordered in a way that the next branch comes up before a new leaf is specified (like the order your example input is already in).
- You parse the input first and structurize it (in a dictionary perhaps) where you will specify at a leaf if there is another branch coming up or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the data structure I would use. I think it's a lot easier to see what's going on than dicts of lists of dicts. The Node print method is a bit more cryptic than I would normally like, but it works.

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self, id, name, parent):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def print(self, indent = ""):

        # Parent node decides how the chid node will be indented
        print("{}{} {}".format(indent, self.id, self.name))
    
        indent = indent.replace('┣', '┃')
        indent = indent.replace('┗', ' ')

        if not self.left is None:
            if self.right is None:
                self.left.print(indent + '┗ ')
            else:
                self.left.print(indent + '┣ ')

        if not self.right is None:
            self.right.print(indent + '┗ ')

def load_data(input_data):

    # Dictionary is used to keep track of nodes while loading.
    nodes = {}

    for id, parentId, name in input_data:

        # Create new node.
        newNode = Node(id, name, parentId)

        # Add new node to parent.
        if parentId == -1:
            if len(nodes) > 0:
                raise Exception("More than one root node in input data")

        elif nodes[parentId].left is None:
            nodes[parentId].left = newNode

        elif nodes[parentId].right is None:
            nodes[parentId].right = newNode

        else:
            raise Exception("Parent node is full")

        # Add new node to dictionary.
        nodes[id] = newNode

    # Return root node.
    return nodes[0]


def main():
    input_data = [
        (0, -1, 'Root'), 
        (1, 0, 'Left branch'), 
        (2, 0, 'Right branch'), 
        (3, 1, 'Left leaf of the Left branch'), 
        (4, 1, 'Right leaf of the Left branch'),
        (5, 2, 'Left leaf of the Right branch'), 
        (6, 2, 'Right leaf of the Right branch'), 
        (7, 6, 'Left side of the Right leaf of the Right branch'), 
        (8, 6, 'Right side of the Right leaf of the Right branch'),
        (9, 4, 'left leaf of Right leaf of the Left branch'),
        (10, 9, 'left leaf of left leaf of Right leaf of the Left branch'),
    ]
    root = load_data(input_data)
    root.print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to build the tree, and then to print, you can use a recursive generator function:

```
data = [[0, -1, 'Root'], [1, 0, 'Left branch'], [2, 0, 'Right branch'], [3, 1, 'Left leaf of the Left branch'], [4, 1, 'Right leaf of the Left branch'], [5, 2, 'Left leaf of the Right branch'], [6, 2, 'Right leaf of the Right branch'], [7, 6, 'Left side of the Right leaf of the Right branch'], [8, 6, 'Right side of the Right leaf of the Right branch']]
def to_tree(p = -1):
  return [{'n':c, 'nodes':to_tree(a)} for a, b, c in data if b == p]

def display_node(n, i, ld, f, c):
   if not c:
      return n
   p_w = ' '*(c-1) if f else ''.join("┃ " for _ in range(c-1))
   return p_w+('┣ ' if i != ld else "┗ ")+n
   
def display_tree(d, f = False, c = 0):
   for i, a in enumerate(d):
      print(display_node(a['n'], i, (ld:=len(d)-1), f, c))
      display_tree(a['nodes'], f = f or i == ld, c=c+1)

display_tree(to_tree())
```

Output:

```
Root
┣ Left branch
┃ ┣ Left leaf of the Left branch
┃ ┗ Right leaf of the Left branch
┗ Right branch
  ┣ Left leaf of the Right branch
  ┗ Right leaf of the Right branch
    ┣ Left side of the Right leaf of the Right branch
    ┗ Right side of the Right leaf of the Right branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone, for your help.
Potential input.txt looks like several lines:

```
0 -1 Root
1 0 Left branch
2 0 Right branch
3 1 Left leaf of the Left branch
4 1 Right leaf of the Left branch
5 2 Left leaf of the Right branch
6 2 Right leaf of the Right branch
7 6 Left side of the Right leaf of the Right branch
8 6 Right side of the Right leaf of the Right branch
```

The code below allows to operate multi-layer tree.

```
import collections
with open('tree.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    tree = f.read()

children_by_id = collections.defaultdict(list)
text_by_id = {}

for line in tree.splitlines():
    id, parent_id, text = line.split(maxsplit=2)
    text_by_id[int(id)] = text
    children_by_id[int(parent_id)].append(int(id))
    
def display_node(p_id=-1, prefix='', prefix2=''):
    if p_id != -1:
        print((prefix[:-2] + prefix2 + text_by_id[p_id])[2:])
    for i, c in enumerate(sorted(children_by_id[p_id], key=lambda x: text_by_id[x])):
        is_last = i == len(children_by_id[p_id]) - 1
        display_node(c, prefix=prefix + ('  ' if is_last else '┃ '),
                        prefix2='┗╸' if is_last else '┣╸')

display_node(-1)
```